# ¿Cómo extraigo un diccionario de otro diccionario?

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente diccionario:

```
miembros = { 1: {"nombre": "Farly Waller", "`pais": "Russia", "siguiendo": [2, 3]},
 
2: {"nombre": "Jania Hardistry", "pais": "Indonesia", "siguiendo": [1, 3]}, 

3: {"nombre": "Yale Shortan", "pais": "Brazil", "siguiendo": [1, 2]}, 

4: {"nombre": "kevin", "pais": "portugal", "siguiendo": []}

 }
```

> En este ejercicio vas a generar un diccionario, asignado a la variable seguidores, con la lista de seguidores agrupados por identificador de usuario
> **Ejemplos**:
>
> - Para el usuario  `1`, el valor debe ser la lista `[2, 3]`.
> - Para el usuario `4`, el valor debe ser la lista vacia (`[]`).

Intenté esto pero no sé cómo:

```
seguidores = {}
for i in miembros seguidores[i] = seguidores.get(i, 0)
```

Comment: `miembros[1]["siguiendo"]`

Comment: seguidores={clave:valor['siguiendo'] for clave,valor in miembros.items()}

Answer (score 1):

Yo entiendo que el ejercicio trata de crear un diccionario "inverso", es decir, un diccionario en el que las claves sean los ids (numeros) de los miembros y los valores sean una lista de quienes son **sus seguidores** (y no de a quiénes sigue cada uno, pues eso ya lo tenías en el diccioario original).

Por desgracia los datos de entrada están elegidos con tan mala fortuna que la lista de a quién sigue cada uno coincide con la lista de quiénes son los seguidores de cada uno.

En efecto, mira. El usuario 1 sigue a los usuarios 2 y 3 (pues eso es lo que tiene en su clave "siguiendo") pero ¿quiénes siguen al usuario 1? Pues resulta que le siguen también los usuarios 2 y 3, ya que el 2 tiene al 1 en su lista "siguiendo" y el 3 también le tiene, pero el 4 no. Y de hecho esta casualidad ocurre con todos los usuarios. El 4 por ejemplo, no sigue a nadie pero a él tampoco le sigue nadie.

No sé si es que estos datos de entrada están mal, o qué. Me parece un ejercicio pésimamente planteado. En todo caso, la solución sería tal que así:

```
# Empezamos creando un diccionario de listas vacías, una por miembro
seguidores = {id: [] for id in miembros }

# Rellenamos apropiadamente las listas
for id_seguidor, datos in miembros.items():
  for id_seguido in datos["siguiendo"]:
    seguidores[id_seguido].append(id_seguidor)
```

Resultado:

```
{1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 2], 4: []}
```

Donde ves lo que decía al principio, que **casualmente** las listas de seguidores coinciden con las listas de seguidos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que acceder de nuevo con su llave.
para el ejemplo 1 seria:
`miembros["1"]["siguiendo"]` esto te da acceso a la lista `[2,3]`

Codigo Completo:

```
miembros = { 1: {"nombre": "Farly Waller", "`pais": "Russia", "siguiendo": [2, 3]},
 
2: {"nombre": "Jania Hardistry", "pais": "Indonesia", "siguiendo": [1, 3]}, 

3: {"nombre": "Yale Shortan", "pais": "Brazil", "siguiendo": [1, 2]}, 

4: {"nombre": "kevin", "pais": "portugal", "siguiendo": []}

 }
seguidores = {}

for key in miembros:
    seguidores[key] = miembros[key]["siguiendo"]
print(seguidores)
```

Output

```
{1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 2], 4: []}
```

Answer (score 0):

un gusto en saludar
Bienvenido a la comunidad

Me parece que quieres interacuar con los valores de los diccionarios a través de las claves

Ahí te corrijo el dataframe que falta una coma y cerrar una doble comilla

```
miembros = { 1: {"nombre": "Farly Waller", "pais": "Russia", "siguiendo": [2, 3]},2: {"nombre": "Jania Hardistry", "pais": "Indonesia", "siguiendo": [ 1,3,4]},3: {"nombre": "Yale Shortan", "pais": "Brazil", "siguiendo": [1,2,4]},4: {"nombre": "kevin", "pais": "portugal", "siguiendo": [1,2]},5: {"nombre": "albero", "pais": "mexico", "siguiendo": []}}
```

Mi propuesta al problema fue esta:

Primero convierto a lista las "keys" del **diccionario miembros** la llamo l_keys

```
l_keys=list(miembros.keys())
```

Ahí sí podría iterar el diccionario miembros, así quedaría el FOR

```
for l_keys in miembros:
    print(miembros[l_keys]['siguiendo'])
    seguidores[l_keys] =miembros[l_keys]['siguiendo']
```

el diccionario final quedaría así

```
print(seguidores)
{1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 3, 4], 3: [1, 2, 4], 4: [1, 2], 5: []}
```

Así como en tu planteamiento lo describes el "*asignado a la variable seguidores, con la lista de seguidores agrupados por identificador de usuario*"

Espero haber contribuido a la solución del problema.

saludos