# Generar un diccionario con for/if python

Tags: python, bucle-for, condiciones, bucles, diccionarios

Tengo el siguiente diccionario:

```
miembros = { 1: {"nombre": "Farly Waller", "`pais": "Russia", "siguiendo": [2, 3]},
 
2: {"nombre": "Jania Hardistry", "pais": "Indonesia", "siguiendo": [ 1,3,4]}, 

3: {"nombre": "Yale Shortan", "pais": "Brazil", "siguiendo": [1,2,4]}, 

4: {"nombre": "kevin", "pais": "portugal", "siguiendo": [1,2]}

5: {"nombre": "albero, "pais": "mexico", "siguiendo": []}
```

}

> En este ejercicio vas a generar un diccionario, asignado a la variable seguidores, con la lista de seguidores agrupados por identificador de usuario
> **Ejemplos**:
>
> - Para el usuario  `1`, el valor debe ser la lista `[2,3 4]`.
> - Para el usuario  `2`, el valor debe ser la lista `[1,3,4]`.
> - Para el usuario  `3`, el valor debe ser la lista `[1,2]`.
> - Para el usuario  `4`, el valor debe ser la lista `[2,3]`.
> - Para el usuario `5`, el valor debe ser la lista vacia (`[]`).

Intenté esto pero no sé cómo:

```
seguidores = {}
for i in miembros seguidores[i] = seguidores.get(i, 0)
```

Comment: Publicar multiples veces la misma pregunta es considerado `spam`. Si algo no estaba bien en la pregunta anterior por favor edítala en lugar de crear una nueva ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo extraigo un diccionario de otro diccionario?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/562270/c%c3%b3mo-extraigo-un-diccionario-de-otro-diccionario)

Comment: No me calza el código con la explicación. El usuario 3 sigue `[1,2,4]` (en el código), pero la explicación dice el resultado esperado es  `[1,2]`

Answer (score 0):

Espero que los comentarios en el código sean lo suficientemente explicativos.

No obstante aquí dejo una pequeña lista de materiales que podés revisar:

- **[ESP]** https://blog.hubspot.es/website/diccionario-python
- **[ESP]** https://docs.hektorprofe.net/python/metodos-de-las-colecciones/metodos-de-los-diccionarios/
- **[ENG]** https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp
- **[ENG]** https://realpython.com/python-dicts/

```py
miembros = {
    1: {"nombre": "Farly Waller", "`pais": "Russia", "siguiendo": [2, 3]},
    2: {"nombre": "Jania Hardistry", "pais": "Indonesia", "siguiendo": [ 1,3,4]}, 
    3: {"nombre": "Yale Shortan", "pais": "Brazil", "siguiendo": [1,2,4]}, 
    4: {"nombre": "kevin", "pais": "portugal", "siguiendo": [1,2]},
    5: {"nombre": "albero", "pais": "mexico", "siguiendo": []}
}

seguidores = dict()

for miembro_id, miembro_datos in miembros.items():
    
    # Recorrer la lista de miembros a quien sigue el miembro actual
    for x in miembro_datos["siguiendo"]:
        
        # Si nadie lo habia seguido antes crear su
        # lista de seguidores vacia
        if not x in seguidores.keys():
            seguidores[x] = []
        
        # Agregar el miembro actual a la listas de
        # seguidores de x
        seguidores[x].append(miembro_id)

print(seguidores)
```

Espero ayude :)
Código en ideone.com: [link](https://ideone.com/e.js/87NLBv)